# How to add a Hyperlink to a tab in Excel?

Tags: excel, hyperlink, ribbon, excel-addins, vba

I want to add a hyperlink to a Tab in Excel. Actually I want to do it as an Excel Add in?
But now it seems there is not option for it by customizing ribbon directly. I know there is document location with a drop down list. But I want a link to a URL. From what I know hyperlinks can be placed on cells only. Please give me some ideas.

Comment: Your description is confusing. Do you want to add a hyperlink to a sheet tab (which isn't possible) the Ribbon or a cell? And a hyperlink can link to a file, an email, a url.. And which drop-down list are you referring to?

Comment: I want to add a link to a url into a new group in a new tab in ribbon . I can insert a new tab and a new group by 'customize ribbon' option.

Comment: I doubt that you can add a hyperlink to the Ribbon. You could add a button, which runs a macro, which creates a `Hyperlink` and uses its `Follow` method.

Comment: I think this question is better answered on [Superuser](http://superuser.com/) , as this is not a programming related question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is a hyperlink, really? Its a text "button" that, when clicked, brings you to a website or opens a link of some sort. 
So in this case, use a button in a tab on the Excel ribbon that when clicked brings you to a website. Easy:

```
Private Sub MyRibbonButton_Click(Byval sender as Object, Byval e as EventArgs) Handles MyRibbonButton.Click

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("my website url")

End Sub
```

Does it look like a button? Of course, but essentially it's just a hyperlink, right?

Comment: That is what I was looking for. I'm new to this Excel. What is the best way to create an addin that adds a vustom tab to ribbon and 3 buttons onto it? Is it using Visual Studio, CustomUI tool or can i make it using Excel itself?

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, you can either make it as a document level project (workbook or template) or as an addin. Either way, once you start the project, press Ctrl + A to add a new control to your project. Select the Ribbon Designer (Visual). Once it's added, from the Toolbox add a button to the ribbon and then add the above code to the button's click event.

Comment: I don't get it if this is the accepted answer why is the question tagged as Excel-VBA

Answer (score 2):

Use a `CustomUI` to create buttons for macros:

```
'To send email
'Callback for customButton onAction
Sub MyWeb(control As IRibbonControl)
Dim oShell As Object
Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    oShell.Run ("http://www.plugpro.com.br")
End Sub

'To Open URL
'Callback for customButton onAction
Sub MyWeb(control As IRibbonControl)
Dim oShell As Object
Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    oShell.Run ("mailto:oton@podium.pro.br")
End Sub
```